# php xdiff_string_diff ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php

When I try to use xdiff_string_diff() page not loaded. I got:

> You can't access this website ... ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

My local config WAMP apache 4.2 php 7.0

phpinfo() got `xdiff enabled`

No errors in php error log

All other pages from localhost loading ok

```
$diff = xdiff_string_diff($string1, $string2, 1);
if (is_string($diff)) {
    echo "Differences between two strings";
    echo $diff;
}
```

**If I disable (comment) the above code the page loading ok**

the string1 and string2 comming from a `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table` SQL query

With `$string1 = "some"` and `$string2 = "some different"` the issue still the same

Answer (score 1):

> My local config WAMP apache 4.2 php 7.0

erm, OK.

> phpinfo() got xdiff enabled

So the extension is loaded - but have you got libxdiff installed and loaded too?

> No errors in php error log

But if you simulate errors in your code they get logged correctly?

And you checked for errors being logged when you startup the webserver?

Sounds like a problem with the xdiff extension. Note that the DLL must be the thread safe version and appropriate 32bit/64 bit for your system.

Comment: Thank's for your time 1. `xdiff support enabled` , `extension version 2.0.1` , `libxdiff version LibXDiff v0.23` 2. What you mean with if I simulate errors ? Using a try catch block ? 3. Apache log `no errors` as startup or trying to load this page 4. The DLL is thread safe version x64 (I have windows 10 x64)

Comment: I mean `trigger_error("This is the message", E_ERROR);`

Comment: if I put `trigger_error("This is the message", E_ERROR);` after my above code nothing happend. The issue still the same errors logs not show nothing new. If i put `trigger_error("This is the message", E_ERROR);` before my above code The issue still the same but in php errors log I got `PHP Warning:  Invalid error type specified in ... my_script_path`

Comment: I have taken a look to `trigger_error` manual and I have changed `E_ERROR` to `E_USER_ERROR`. So nothing happend. Page not loaded (still `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` ) ... and no errors in errors logs (even if I put them before my code)

Comment: Then you have a problem with your logging. Fix that and you may discover why xdiff_string_diff() is failing.

Comment: Nope. Because if I delete the code mentioned above and I leave only the `trigger_error('msg',E_USER_ERROR)` .. then page is loaded correctly, print one `Fatal Error` and inside  php error log also the same error as printed appear. So I think if some from the extension. Thank you for all ... for the moment will use https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff instead

Comment: Sorry in mi penultimate comment I have maded a mistake that are confusing you. So with `trigger_error("This is the message", E_USER_ERROR);` before my code the page load correctly ... show `Fatal Error` and php error log also.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have exact same problem.

Comment: @Radium I have only used this for some specific tests of mine (which I don't even remember well).
But if you look at one of my comments above, I said that I used https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff
Sorry...it's the only thing I remember about this topic